# Google App Engine Channels API / Loading external JS with React Native

Tags: require, channel-api, react-native

I'm in the process of porting a project to React Native, previously i referenced an the google channels api from an external server for web sockets e.g. https://example.com/_ah/channel/jsapi.

Is there an elegant way I can reference  this using React Native ?

Comment: What did you referenced the API with? A script tag?

Comment: Yep just via a script tag originally

Comment: any people have find an answer to this question?

Comment: Sigh. Google is depreciating the channel api in favour of Firebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Channels API is doomed, favour firebase or some standard websocket implementation in projects